# Matlab: fill Command Adds Two Elements to Legend. How to Avoid This

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, figure

I am working on a Matlab project in which I need to use the `fill` command. The `fill` command fill(X,Y,C) creates filled polygons from the data in X and Y with vertex color specified by C.

I've got the following code:

```
x_2 = [x, fliplr(x)];
inBetween = [Auf1_mW_pro_mg(1781:length(Auf1_mW_pro_mg)), fliplr(y_Temp)];
figure('Name','Test')
fill(x_2, inBetween, 'r','facealpha',.5,'LineStyle','none');
legend()
```

... ,which gets me this result:

[image]

As you can see I've got two areas because my data is real data and the extrapolated line does not always only have the data-line above it.

Does anybody have a simple idea how to avoid two data elements being displayed in the legend in this scenario? Deleting elements form the legend does not seem to be something that is easily accomplished, which was my first idea. Maybe I can get control over which data is added to the legend?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `legend('data1')` instead of `legend()`

Comment: This does help. However I've got a longer legend in my actual project, so this only helps if I use the fill command last in the figure created, which has other plots before that. In this case I can cut of the legend at one point, by just not supporting any more string elements. However if I would like to show this particular data in the middle of the legend the issue cannot be resolved solely by this.

Comment: Hi Timon, please see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62010048/5698672)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fill` shows up twice in the legend, two patches are created. You can set the visibility of these individual patches for the `legend`. First store the handles of the graphics objects

```
h = fill(x_2, inBetween, 'r','facealpha',.5,'LineStyle','none');
```

This will return a 2×1 Patch array, of which you can set the `HandleVisibility` property for the second element:

```
h(2).HandleVisibility = 'off';
```

Now it won't show in your legend. But functions like `findobj` also cannot find the patch, more details on the consequences [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/preventing-access-to-figures-and-axes.html)).

Comment: This is the easiest way to accomplish what I desired, with the downsides mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Just keep and use the handles of the objects that you want to show in the legend.

**Example:**

Reproducing your issue first:

```
t = (1/16:1/8:1).'*pi;   x = sin(t);   y = cos(t);
%Making the plots now
plot(t,x,'r','linewidth',2);
hold on;
h1 = plot(t,y,'b','linewidth',2); %We want to show this in the legend
h2 = fill([x fliplr(x)],fliplr(y),'g'); %and one entry only for this
plot(x,y,'k','linewidth',2);
```

Now `legend()` gives us:

[image]

We can fix this using the handles of the desired objects as follows:

```
legend([h1, h2(1)]);
% or if we want to name these objects then:
% legend([h1, h2(1)],'Line Plot','Filled Polygon');
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to still add text to the legend for the according data? So instead of "data1" and "data2" i would like to have e.g. "legend1" and "legend2".

Comment: As mentioned in the last (commented) line of the code: you can use: `legend([h1,h2(1)],'legend1','legend2');`